# Por que Button dentro da Label não funciona. O Button não funciona como o esperado não ativa o Checkbox

Tags: html, html5

Eu estava fazendo um Menu que só aparece quando um `checkbox` está checado. E para alterar o estado desse `checkbox` eu preciso clicar na `label` dela, já que o `input:checkbox` está na verdade oculto.

O que acontece é que dentro da `label` eu coloquei um `button`, e dessa forma não consigo ativar o `checkbox`... Veja que segundo a documentação dentro da `label` são permitidos todos os `Phrasing_content`https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Sobre os: [Phrasing Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)

Repare que aqui tenho dos códigos, um que não funciona com o `button` dentro, e outro que funciona sem o `button`.

**Então, porque a `label` como o `button` dentro não ativa o `checkbox`?**

```css
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + nav {
  display: block;
}
label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="btnx"><button>button</button></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="btnx">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>item 01</li>
    <li>item 02</li>
    <li>item 03</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br><br>
<label for="btny">label</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="btny">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>item 04</li>
    <li>item 05</li>
    <li>item 06</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o `<label>` possui apenas um filho interativo e, por padrão, a interação com esses elementos não devem ativar o `<label>`. Veja o trecho da [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element):

> *The label element's exact default presentation and behavior, in particular what its activation behavior might be, if anything, should match the platform's label behavior. The activation behavior of a label element for events targeted at interactive content descendants of a label element, and any descendants of those interactive content descendants, must be to do nothing.*

Em tradução livre, "a apresentação e o comportamento padrão exatos do elemento `<label>`, em especial qual deve ser seu comportamento de ativação, deve corresponder ao comportamento do `<label>` da plataforma. O comportamento de ativação de um elemento de `<label>` para eventos destinados **a descendentes de conteúdo interativo** de um elemento de rótulo e quaisquer descendentes desses descendentes de conteúdo interativo **deve ser o de não fazer nada**".

Ou seja, o clique no botão dentro do `<label>` não ativa o clique do `<label>`, bem como em nenhum elemento interativo:

```html
Alvo: <input type="checkbox" id="check">

<div>
  <p>Teste com o campo de texto:</p>
  <label for="check">
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Teste com o campo de checkbox:</p>
  <label for="check">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Teste com o campo de radio:</p>
  <label for="check">
    <input type="radio">
  </label>
</div>
```

Perceba que nenhuma interação com os elementos dentro do `<label>` ativa a seleção do checkbox.

Curiosamente isso não é um problema com o alvo do `<label>`, pois se verificarmos o valor do atributo `control` no JavaScript, que possui uma referência ao elemento alvo, veremos que será o próprio `<input type="checkbox">` como definimos com o atributo `for`.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('label[for="btnx"]');

console.log(label.control);
```

```css
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
nav {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + nav {
  display: block;
}
label {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="btnx"><button>button</button></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="btnx">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>item 01</li>
    <li>item 02</li>
    <li>item 03</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br><br>
<label for="btny">label</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="btny">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>item 04</li>
    <li>item 05</li>
    <li>item 06</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Acredito que deva ser isso mesmo. Muito completa a resposta, []´s

Comment: Legal, a explicação técnica é exatamente essa. Fui ler a documentação e lá diz que o `tabindex` transforma qualquer elemento em "conteúdo interativo", mas se você colocar um `<span tabindex="1">foo</span>` dentro do label e clicar nele, irá ativar o label. Vai entender! rs...

Comment: @Sam, interativo acho que apenas no sentido de entrar na lista de navegação pelo teclado, talvez para outros fins não. Onde viu esta informação?

Comment: Nesta página: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content, no item 3.2.4.2.7